Doubt in proof about congruence of triangles?
I'm reading Coxeter's Introduction to Geometry. He suggests this axiom:



Plus the following axioms (I assume he suggests we can prove this using only these axioms but it's not too clear for me if that is the case).



To prove the following proposition:



I tried the following, given the two triangles:
We want to prove that $B_1C_1=B_2C_2$, using the previous theorem, we define the sides $A_iD_i$ to be $V_iX_i$ and we define $C_i=W_i$:



Now we construct $B_i$ such that the length of $B_iC_i$ is equal to $D_iC_i$:



Now it's a bit confusing to me, how can we know that $A_1B_1$ and $A_2B_2$ have the same length?

What is known data in your question? According to the diagram, do we know that  $V_iX_iW_i$ are congruent already?

@Gwen Sorry, I miscolored. We know that $W_iV_i$ and $W_iX_i$ are congruent but we don't know if $A_iV_i$ are congruent.

Do we have data about the $\theta$ that you have coloured? Are they congruent?

@Gwen Yes, they are congruent.

Then we can apply the SAS axiom of congruency to prove that the triangles $V_iX_iW_i$ are congruent. You can even prove this axiom using the cosine formula.

@Gwen I know but I am specifically trying to prove it with the axiom Coxeter suggested in his book.

Coxeter's book presumes a fair amount of foundational/historical knowledge, and he goes out of his way to deal with an early issue that geometers recognized starting in Euclid's Elements.
Elements I.4 is the side-angle-side theorem. Eulid's approach is, in essence, to superpose and then say "see?". He hardly ever does that, but he prominently does it in the very first proof of triangle congruence, which of course is the foundation of much to follow (including SSS, AAS, ASA). The first five axioms you mention above are Euclid's.
Greek and Roman commentators and geometers following often amended Euclid's axioms by adding an additional axiom like "two right lines cannot enclose a space". Meaning that if 2 points are endpoints of a line segment, one and only one line segment may have those endpoints, for otherwise, 2 would, and that would enclose a space. This add-on lets the superposition argument work convincingly in a way it didn't in Elements.
Coxeter in his text refers to axiom I.26 as enabling rigid translation - the essence of superposition. In it, SAS is axiomatically embedded in the exterior of the triangle - the congruence is one of SAS in triangle $ACD$ (with simple precursor steps of a subtraction to find $CD=C'D'$ and lines containing 2 right angles so $\angle{ACD}=\angle{A'C'D'}$. The overall point is that SAS must be nearly, or just simply, axiomatic. Also these days we like to discuss geometries in terms of transformations (like translation) so we like explicit acknowledgment and discussion of what rigidity is and what role it plays in arguments for congruence.
Edit: Coxeter will continue to discuss specific proofs from Euclid - he presumes the reader knows them. If you have not read the first 6 books of Elements, but do know some geometry, I would do that now before going farther with Coxeter. It will take you a few hours or days to go through, but you'll understand more of Coxeter's book after that. Google "clark elements" for an online version, there is a nice version by Green Lion press in print, and many scans of 19th century textbooks are online too.


We coincide $W_i$s of the two triangles such that $X_1V_2$ and $X_2V_1$ are straight lines. This can only be done due to the angles being equal.
Now, we know $V_1W=V_2W$ and $X_2W=X_1W$ so if we add them, $X_1V_2=V_1X_2$. And $V_1V_2=V_2V_1$ as they are common for both triangles.
So by using the first axiom ($1.26$), we can conclude that $XiV_i$ are congruent.
